# how to use ffmpeg-php extension

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I have downloaded PHP extension files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/

There are lots of files in the package. I want to know that how can I use this as a PHP Extension. I thought they will provide .dll files as other extension. But in this case there are lots of file,

I am running on windows 7, PHP 5.2.9, Apache 2.2.15

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since it only builds with Visual C, you will need to install that. (And learn how to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

The files you downloaded are the source code for `ffmpeg-php`. They need to be compiled and since you're on Windows, that might not be that simple.

Instead, follow these instructions: http://ironlasso.com/install_ffmpeg-php_windows.html. The link include a link to a pre-complied version which will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: @Avinash - Windows doesn't come with a compiler. You'll need to purchase/download Visual C or some other C compiler.